# Can I avoid using plainPassword property and only use password in Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, authentication, passwords, password-encryption, symfony4

Symfony documentation mentions that there should be two Password properties(password and plainPassword). The plainPassword is only used to get the password that a user typed(e.g via a registration form) and is not persisted by doctrine(hence not stored in the database). Password property on the other hand is set after encrypting the plainPassword. Is it not possible to use the same property (password) to collect the plainPassword from the user to avoid having two password properties?

Here is my controller code:

```
class SecurityController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/register", name="security_register")
 */
public function register(Request $request, 
UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncode)
{
    $user = new User();

    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $email = $form->get('email')->getData();

        $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
        $user->setPassword($password);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin');
    }

    return $this->render(
        'security/register.html.twig',
        array('form' => $form->createView())
    );
}
```

And here my User Entity:

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Email()
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
 */
private $plainPassword;

/**
 * The below length depends on the "algorithm" you use for encoding
 * the password, but this works well with bcrypt.
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 */
private $password;


/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;
}

public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;
}

public function getPlainPassword()
{
    return $this->plainPassword;
}

public function setPlainPassword($password)
{
    $this->plainPassword = $password;
}

public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;
}

public function getSalt()
{
    // The bcrypt and argon2i algorithms don't require a separate salt.
    // You *may* need a real salt if you choose a different encoder.
    return null;
}

// other methods, including security methods like getRoles()

public function getRoles()
{
    return array('ROLE_ADMIN');
}

public function eraseCredentials()
{
}

/** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt,
    ));
}

/** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
}
}
```

Comment: Not the way you're using it. Is there a specific issue with it that you're having or is it that you just don't want it?

It's basically a placeholder field for you to use to not have to overwrite your existing password in case of an error.

Comment: It was just out of curiosity. The logic of avoiding overwriting the existing password in case of errors explains it. Thank you very much @JacobW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason Symfony suggests to use a plainPassword field is that by using directly the password field in your registration form, you could end up with an unencrypted password in your database in case you don't implement correctly the encryption procedure before storing the user. And that would be a huge security issue.